# how to decrement in if elif statement

Tags: python

I'm trying to decrement `multiplier` by 1 when the result is exceeding the value of `cap` until it is equal or less than `cap`.

I have tried this:

```
max_c = c_var1 * 12

if max_c >= 203:
    max_c = c_var1 * 11

elif max_c >= 203:
    max_c = c_var1 * 10

var1 = int(input("")
c_var1 = var1 / 10
cap = int("203")
multiplier = int("12")

max_c = c_var1 * multiplier

if max_c >= cap:
    max_c = c_var1 * (multiplier - 1)

elif max_c >=cap:
    max_c = c_var1 * (multiplier - 1)
```

I'm expecting the code to decrement the multiplier when the result is exceeding the value of `cap`, but it always stops at the first `if` even though the result is greater than the value of `cap`.

Comment: Your `if `and `elif` test the same thing.

Comment: As @gmds said, no one can understand what you want to do.

Comment: Also, first you have to define `c_var1` before doing multiplication using this variable.

Comment: @YangHG what i want to do is decrease the multiplier by 1 if the result from max_c is greater than cap value until it is equal or less than the cap variable

Comment: and i'm so sorry my english is really bad

Comment: @Yusufsn how to define c_var1?

Comment: Your code in line 6 and 7 should be written at the beginning of your code. Could you please provide your expected output? Or just give an example of the input and the output if your code works well.

Comment: if the code works well i'm expecting the output from `max_c` is not greater or at least equal the value in `cap`